# Compare the two versions of dataframes for Upsert and list out changes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I am doing upsert operation in databricks. Now I want to check what is changed between two upsert operation.

My original `df1` look like this>>
[image: My 1st Dataframe]

My upserted `df2` look like this >> [image: My 2nd Dataframe]

I want Output like this>>
[image: Output Dataframe]

here `id` is my `primary_key`

Comment: Join df1 on df2. Action column if df1.id is not null => updated, else inserted. From there add the old_age and old_city in case of update. Then pivot the whole thing.

Comment: Can you explain more on pivot

Answer (score 1):

Simpler would be to enable [Change Data Feed](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html) on the given Delta Table - then you can read all changes between - inserts/updates/deletes, and you can consume these changes either as batch or as stream:

```py
all_changes = spark.read.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .option("startingVersion", 0) \
  .option("endingVersion", 10) \
  .table("myDeltaTable")
inserts = all_changes.filter("__change_type = 'insert'")
updates = all_changes.filter("__change_type = 'update_postimage'")
deletes = all_changes.filter("__change_type = 'delete'")
```